# Activity in paused state

Tags: android, android-activity

There's a sentence in the definition of activity state 'paused': "...but can be killed by the system in extremely low memory situations."

Does it mean that there's no way to develop alarm clock which can guarantee it will go off "no matter what"?

If it can simply be killed, people will be late to work.

Comment: Alarm manager helps you in all that u need regarding alarms.

Comment: are you considering having a activity perpetually in pause until the alarm is set to go off, or am i misunderstanding?

Answer (score 1):

The AlarmManager would most likely be used to trigger an alarm.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

You would use an Activity to display the clock.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Service which runs in the background to achieve that functionality

Answer (score 0):

If you go for an alarm clock app, you need to look at the Service class or AlarmManager of Android

- A [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) is a process which runs on background (always, if you
  don't stop it)
- [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) is another approach, where your specify something to do at a specific time

Comment: A service can be killed by android when running low on memory (although android will try to restart it when some memory is freed up)